# How to force codeset cp1252 for output file in perl >=5.18 within Windows 10?

Tags: windows, perl, encoding, strawberry-perl, cp1252

I need to make shure that the output file i create with my perl script has the codeset cp1252 and not UTF-8 because it will be used within a UNIX SQLplus framework which handles german "umlauts" not correctly when it insert that values into the database columns (I use strawberry perl v5.18 within Windows 10 and i cannot set NLS_LANG or chcp within the UNIX SQL environment).

With this little test script i can reproduce that the output file "testfile1.txt" is allways in UTF-8 but "testfile2.txt" is CP1252 as expected.
How can i force the output for "testfile1.txt" to be also CP1252 even if there are no "special" chars within the text ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -w
use strict;
use Encode;

# the result file under Windows 10 will have UTF-8 codeset
open(OUT,'> testfile1.txt');    
binmode(OUT,"encoding(cp-1252)");
print OUT encode('cp-1252',"this is a test");
close(OUT);

# the result file under Windows 10 will have Windows-cp1252 codeset
open(OUT,'> testfile2.txt');    
binmode(OUT,"encoding(cp-1252)");
print OUT encode('cp-1252',"this is a test with german umlauts <ÄäÜüÖöß>");
close(OUT);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your question is based on a misunderstanding. `testfile1.txt` contains the text `this is a test`. These characters have the same encoding in ASCII, Latin-1, UTF-8, and CP-1252. `testfile1.txt` is valid in all of these encodings simultaneously.

---

To include literal Unicode characters in your source code like this:

```
print OUT encode('cp-1252',"this is a test with german umlauts <ÄäÜüÖöß>");
```

you need

```
use utf8;
```

at the top.

Also, don't combine encoding layers on filehandles with explicit `encode()` calls. Either set an encoding layer and print Unicode text to it, or use `binmode(OUT)` and print raw bytes (as returned from `encode()`) to it.

---

By the way, you shouldn't use `-w` anymore. It's been supplanted by the

```
use warnings;
```

pragma.

Similarly, bareword filehandles and two-argument open are pre-5.6 style code and shouldn't be used in code written after 2000. (perl 5.005 and earlier didn't support Unicode/encodings anyway.)

A fixed version of your code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

{
    open(my $out, '>:encoding(cp-1252)', 'testfile1.txt') or die "$0: testfile1.txt: $!\n";    
    print $out "this is a test\n";
    close($out);
}

{
    open(my $out, '>encoding(cp-1252)', 'testfile2.txt') or die "$0: testfile2.txt: $!\n";    
    print $out "this is a test with german umlauts <ÄäÜüÖöß>\n";
    close($out);
}
```

Comment: _Schei� Encoding..._ :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for that fast and great answer. So the "encoding type" is not stored as a "key" within the file but it will just defined by its binary values stored in it, right ?
My missunderstatement came from the case that my editor gives me the option to store a file with a selected codeset .. By the way, what is the reason to enclose the two "open" statement within brackets ?

Comment: @drvolk Correct. Text files don't store their own encoding. Programs have to just know somehow what the encoding is (or take a guess based on the bytes in the file, but that can go wrong). The blocks in my code are to limit the scope of the `$out` handle.